# Expression for $2^{ω(n)}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

My goal is to derive the expression: $$2^{ω(n)}=\sum\limits_{d|n} q_2(d)$$ where for $n\in \mathbb{N}$:

$ω(n)$ denotes the **number of distinct prime divisors**, namely:

$$ 
ω(n)= \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      0, &n=1 \\
      k, &n=p_1^{a_1}\dots p_k^{a_k},\: p_i\:distinct\:\:primes,1\leq a_i \\
\end{array} 
\right.  $$

and for fixed $m\geq 2$, $q_m(n)$ denotes whether **n is free of $m$-th powers**, namely:

$$
q_m(n)= \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      1, &p^m\nmid n,for\:\:all\:\:primes\:\:p|n \\
      0, &else \\
\end{array} 
\right.  $$

So, let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and write it as $n=p_1^{a_1}\dots p_k^{a_k}$, with $p_i$ distinct primes and $a_i\geq 1,\forall i=1,\dots,k$.
We have $ω(n)=k$. 
The divisors of $\:n\:$ are **exactly** the numbers $\:d\:$,$\:$ of the form $\:d=\:p_1^{b_1}\dots p_k^{b_k}$, $0\leq b_i\leq a_i$.

Hence, $$q_2(d)=1\iff 0\leq b_i\leq 1\forall i=1,\dots k$$

But that means that the sum $\:\sum\limits_{d|n} q_2(d)$ is exactly the sum of $1$'s, over the number of all the possible combinations of $\;p_1,\dots,p_k$. 
Which means:

$$\sum\limits_{d|n} q_2(d)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k}{i}=2^k=2^{ω(n)} $$

I know that another way to show this equality is to prove that $2^{ω(n)}$ and $q_2(n)$ are both multiplicative, and then just show that the equality with the "wanted" sum holds for $n=1$ and $n=p^a$ for a prime $p$ and $a\geq 1$, but I'm just curious if my proof is correct.

For anyone interested, the context is that I wanted to find an asymptotic estimate for $\:\sum\limits_{n\leq x} 2^{ω(n)}$ and the hint "write $2^{ω(n)}$ as $(d*g)(n)$,$\:$ where $d(n)$ is the number of divisors function, $g(n)$ is an arithmetic function needed to be found and $d*g$ denotes the usual **Dirichlet Convolution** of arithmetic functions" wasn't really helpful.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: The proof looks correct to me.

Comment: I've added the `solution-verification` tag to the question.